# DirectX 11 errors equivalent to DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx-11, directx-9, dxgi

I need a reference for finding equivalent error codes for DirectX 11 that was used in DirectX 9 implementations like following:

```
D3DERR_INVALIDDEVICE
D3DERR_DRIVERINVALIDCALL
D3DERR_TOOMANYOPERATIONS
D3DERR_DEVICELOST
D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET
D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE
```

I have found that winerror.h contains all the DXGI error codes but could not find equivalent code for the above mentioned errors in DiretcX 9.
Please help me finding a reference or wiki to find an equivalent error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXGI-based versions of Direct3D do not have 'lost device' scenarios, only [TDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/timeout-detection-and-recovery) and [device removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios), so the `D3DERR_DEVICELOST`, `D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET`, `D3DERR_DRIVERINTERNALERROR`, and `D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE` cases never happen with Direct3D 10 or later.

As documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3derr), you will never get `D3DERR_DRIVERINVALIDCALL`.

`D3DERR_TOOMANYOPERATIONS`, `D3DERR_CONFLICTINGRENDERSTATE`, `D3DERR_CONFLICTINGTEXTUREFILTER`, etc. applies to the legacy fixed-function pipeline which doesn't exist for Direct3D 10 or later.

A number of these older errors like `D3DERR_UNSUPPORTEDALPHAARG`, `D3DERR_UNSUPPORTEDALPHAOPERATION`, etc. were related to the old legacy "caps bits" which is not how things are managed for Direct3D 10 or later. Instead, it uses [Direct3D hardware feature levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro).

In cases where Direct3D9 would return `D3DERR_INVALIDDEVICE` you probably get `E_INVALIDARG` now.

> You may want to look at [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/)